# CPUSET, isolate a core

Tags: linux

I am using CPUSET to isolate a specific core. But I have some doubts about CPUSET. I use the next script to isolate:

```
mkdir /cpuset
mount -t cpuset none /cpuset/
cd /cpuset
mkdir sys
echo 0-2 > sys/cpus 
echo 1 > sys/cpu_exclusive
echo 0 > sys/mems       
mkdir rt
echo 3 > rt/cpus
echo 1 >  rt/cpu_exclusive
echo 0 > rt/mems
echo 0 > rt/sched_load_balance
echo 1 > rt/mem_hardwall
for T in `cat tasks`; do echo "Moving " $T; echo $T > sys/tasks; done
```

When the operating system create a new task how can I sure that it will not be schedule in my isolated partition (in my case, in my 3 core)?

There is a python tool called CSET to make using the cpusets facilities in the Linux kernel easier, and it has an option to remove unbounded kernel threads for a specific partition, how can I do this using directly CPUSET?

Comment: CPU affinity settings can be used to specify which CPUs to use

Comment: I know it, but when a new task is created without cpu affinity where will it be placed?

Comment: Operating system's default affinity